# Python - Flask - Request.form not working

Tags: python, json, backbone.js, flask

I'm working with the Flask framework for Python, and I am trying to use backbone.js as a frontend, at the end of the function, I do

```
return jsonify(results=data)
```

to return a json result. The issue here, however, is that backbone cannot accept the results namespace, and I cannot find a way to go without it. Ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, and seems to be more of a Backbone issue than a Flask one. Can you update your question with actual errors and traces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a model you should be returning your model attributes. If it is a collection you should be returning a list of the attributes of the collection's models .

Now if you have a look at what `jsonify` actually does, you will find out that it constructs a dict with whatever args and kwargs you pass it and calls `json.dumps` (or simplejson.dumps for older pythons).

So if you return a model

`return jsonify({'id': 'foo', 'title' :'Foo'})`

or even

`return jsonify(id='foo', title='Foo')`

For a collection

`return jsonify([{'id': 'foo', 'title': 'Foo'}, {'id': 'bar', 'title': 'Bar'}])`